# How to show another page in adobe muse lightbox?

Tags: adobe, lightbox, html, muse

I have a product page in my website, and i want to show a lightbox showing another page every time a product was clicked. How can i do it using Adobe Muse?

Answer (score -2):

I'm a little confused about exactly what it is you are after and as my Rep isn't enough I'm unable to comment.

With the Lightbox, if you select 'hide all initially' you can insert all of the product info in each of the Lightbox triggers.

Is that what you were after?